# How can I create a variable in a service that gets its data from a promise yet is shared between two components?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service in an Angular 2 using TypeScript. I want to be able to share an array of values that I get from that service. when one component makes a change to the array I need it to be reflected in another component.

This is the basics of my service and the object it uses

```
export class deviceObj {
  device_Id:number;
  deviceGroup_Id:number;
  name:string;
  favoriteFlag:boolean;
  visibleFlag:boolean;

}

export class Favorite {
    favorite_Id: number;
    device: deviceObj;
    constructor(){this.device = new deviceObj()};

}


@Injectable()
export class FavoriteService {
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    private favoritesURL = 'URL THAT FEETCHES DATA';
    favorites: Favorite[];
    constructor(private http: Http) {

    this.getFavorites().then(favorites => this.favorites = favorites);

}

getFavorites(): Promise<Favorite[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.favoritesURL).toPromise().then(response => response.json() as Favorite[]).catch(this.handleError);


}

protected handleError2(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'server error');
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // 
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}


}
```

And here is one of the components that gets the array of favorites.

```
 import {FavoriteService} from'../../services/favorite/favorite.service';
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: '[sidebar]',
  directives: [
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    SlimScroll
  ],
  template: require('./sidebar.html')
})

export class Sidebar implements OnInit {


  constructor(config: ConfigService, el: ElementRef, router: Router, location: Location,
  private favoriteService:FavoriteService) {

  }
getFavorites(): void{
    this.favoriteService
        .getFavorites()
        .then(favorites => this.favorites = favorites);

}
```

In each component that uses the service it has its own favorites array that gets assigned on load. However I want a singleton variable in the service where changes can be reflected in two components. I'm not sure how to do this with promises. I am happy to clarify further if needed. Any help would greatly be apreciated.

Comment: In your component get/set favorites array from service model.
this.favoriteService.favorites will work as singleton.

Comment: @user32 If I create a get method it will return before the promise has been fullfilled. how to I make it so that it will return on promise success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it can probably be done with Promises, I can answer in the form of Observables at the very least, if you're of a mind to read about them...

Given `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` both looking at a `SharedService` for their source of `SomeObject[]` data:

The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs/rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

import { SomeObject } from './some-object';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService{
    SharedList$: Observable<SomeObject[]>;
    private listObserver: Observer<SomeObject[]>;

    private sharedList: SomeObject[];

    constructor(private http: Http){
        this.sharedList = [];
        this.SharedList$ = new Observable<SomeObject[]>(x => this.listObserver = x).share();
    }

    getList(){
        // Get the data from somewhere, i.e. http call
        this.http.get(...)
            .map(etc)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.sharedList = res;
                this.listObserver.next(this.sharedList);
            });
        // the important part is after getting the data you want, observer.next it
    }

    addItem(item: SomeObject): void {
        this.sharedList.push(item);
        this.listObserver.next(this.sharedList);
    }
}
```

Components then have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs/rx';

import { SharedService } from './some.service';

import { SomeObject } from './some-object';

@Component({...})
export class CommponentA implements OnInit {
    private list: SomeObject[];

    constructor(private service: SharedService){
        this.list = [];
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.service.SharedList$.subscribe(lst => this.list = lst);
        this.service.getList();
    }

    private onClick(item: SomeItem): void {
        this.service.addItem(item);
    }
}
```

`ComponentB` would look similar - subscribing to the same `SharedList$` property on the service. When the service's `getList()` method is called, and it pushes a new `SomeObject[]` through the observables (`this.listObserver.next(..)`), the components subscribed to that property will be able to read the value pushed to it.

Edit: Exposed an `addItem` method on the service that the components can call to push items to the list. The service then pushes it through the observable, (`this.listObserver.next(...)`) in the same style as when getting the data through x other method (i.e. http).

Comment: I will try this and report back

Comment: So this is where I am stuck now. 

How do I add an element to SharedList$ or listObserver? so if on one component I need to add another object how do I do that?

Comment: In order to add a variable to the list that my service is sharing do I need to immediately save to the data base and get this list again? I want to be able to do something like this

in component a


`addToList(SomeObject ){
 this.service.addToList(SomeObject)
}
`
And then have that object shown on component B. Which is the whole point of having a service. I could just retreive that values individually in each component otherwize.

Comment: @Nothing Exactly. I'll update my answer for you to include this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However there is one thing I believe that is keeping it from working. I think it may be this 

`share()`

it keeps complaining saying its not a function.Is there any other way to make it shared?

I get this error
`TypeError: (intermediate value).share is not a function
    at new FavoriteService`

Comment: Edit nevermind I got it to work. it was an import problem needed this line
`import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs/Rx';`

Thanks so much you saved me. I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @Nothing You're welcome. Glad I can actually provide someone with help for once!

Comment: Hi, I have a similar scenario where in I want to call the getList before componentA and componentB gets loaded and they can share the data from SharedList but since we are calling get list after subscribing in componentA, it throws error and I assume that we wont be calling getList method in component B

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari - quick and dirty solution would be to add a basic getter to the service for the list `get serviceList(): any[] { return this._serviceList; }`. In your components, you can get the current state of the list followed by subscribing to it for future updates: `this._myList = this.service.serviceList; this.service.serviceList$.subscribe(x => this._myList = x);`.

Comment: Hey Krenom, thanks for the solution though being dirty, but could you confirm whether it is good to add something in app.module.ts under provider section as { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (common: CommonService) => () => common.load(), deps: [CommonService], multi: true }] this loads the commonService load method before the application is loaded and the data is available for both the components?

Comment: You're welcome. Is this service on a module along with those components or is it generally part of the app? It sounds as though you could be doing this in the app component itself. If you need data loading at startup, the app component ngOnInit would be the place to do it. One danger, though, is trying to push data through your observable without having anything subscribed to it (throw away sub on the app to satisfy the need?...)

Answer (score 2):

@Krenom's answer was corrrect. with one  import needing to be changed on my setup.

I needed `import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs/Rx';import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs/Rx';`

Answer (score -1):

In your component

```
//set favorites
    getFavorites(): void{
        this.favoriteService
            .getFavorites()
            .then(favorites => this.favoriteService.favorites = favorites);
    }  

// get favorite
this.favorites = this.favoriteService.favorites;//access it from service
```

Comment: This seems to make a copy and not pass a reference. So it comes out empty before the the promise has finished