# Angular 2: Is there a way of handling Observable (async) in the Component instead of of using the pipe in the template?

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm currently using Observable for fetching some data in an Angular 2 app, however I only want to send the data for display in my template after the request is completed.  I know there is the use of "myValue | async" however for the purpose of this app I need to capture the value in a variable and send that variable (with the final value) to my template.  This is my code

```
     dataRetrieved() {
     this._privateVariable.getData();//this subscribes to an observable
     return true;//if the request was completed
 }
```

Is there a way to do that?  Thank you!

Update:

Thank you for your replies.  Here is a better sample of what I have:

JSON:

```
        { 
        "data": 
           {
             "id" : 1,
              "dataDescription": "dummy text data to save"
            } 
         }
```

HTML template:

```
<div>[ngmodel] = 'myVariable' </div> <!--myVariable should contain the value of "dataDescription" from my json object.  Here when I use the pipe/async instead of a variable I get an error  (_myPrivateVariable.myData | async)?.dataDescription  -->
```

MyComponent:

```
  constructor (private _privateVariable: MyService){}
    ngOnInit() {


  this._privateVariable.getData();//this retrieves a json object, I want to be able to retrieve the value I need here instead that in the view using "| async"
```

MyService:

```
  private _myData:BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});


 public myData: Observable<any> = this._myData.asObservable();


   getData (): Observable<any> {
    let obs = this._http.get(URL).cache();
    obs.subscribe( (response : Response) => {
        let responseData = response.json();            
        this._myData.next(responseData.data);

    });
```

In the end, all I need is to set myVariable = "dummy text data to save", makes sense?

Thank you!

Comment: subscribe to an observable and store it in variable. what's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing, is just that when I try to do it, it doesn't come up.  As of now I'm trying to retrieve an element within the JSON array that gets return, but the only way I know how to do it is using "|asyc" in my template, makes sense?

Comment: When you subscribe to an observable, you don't have to use `|async`.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm a rookie so please bear with me here :).  Maybe I'm asking the wrong question, but how can I access a column within my JSON array?

Comment: tell me your JSON array and which column you want to access. also show how you use in template.

Comment: Thank you!  Ok, my JSON looks like this:

{
    "data":
    {
       "dataDescription": "dummy text data to save"

    }
}

When this data gets retrieved it will always be like this, so it's sort of scalar.

So the getData method retrieves that from my componenet.  In the associated template
I need to tie its contents like this: 

<div [(ngModel)]='myVariable'>

Comment: I told you to add html as well. show me how you use in html.

Comment: You don't have a JSON array, you need to actually `.subscribe` to the observable and provide a callback for it to be resolved with. Please give a [mcve] of service, view and controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#async-pipe) handles the subscription for you. In case you want to do the subscription manually you can always subscribe to an Observable and handle the update of the variable(s) yourself.

[See this plnkr for demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/YRd4QWxCz21TIq8ZTBDM).

Relevant code:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import "rxjs/add/observable/interval";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Counter with async: {{ counter | async }}</p>
      <p>Counter without async: {{ subscribedCounter }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  counter: Observable<number>;
  subscribedCounter: number;
  constructor() {
    this.counter = Observable.interval(1000);
    this.counter.subscribe(
      v => { this.subscribedCounter = v; }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you chromate!  The "subscribedCounter " is exactly what I need, maybe my issue is dealing with the json object, can you give me your input on the update I provided?

Comment: The best example I have found. Thanks!

Comment: using `next` as the variable name is a bit confusing, since `next` is used to refer to a subscriber callback function name, not the value, perhaps rename it?

Answer (score 0):

My answer to...

[How can I create a variable in a service that gets its data from a promise yet is shared between two components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897670/how-can-i-create-a-variable-in-a-service-that-gets-its-data-from-a-promise-yet-i/39898499#39898499)

... covers a basic example of what you want to do (from your Updated question).