# Http Get - How to maintain state?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm a bit confused about angular Http Get observable. I want to assign the results of my observable to my class variable. If I log inside the subscribe, it prints the class variable OK. If I log outside of the subscribe, it shows an empty array. How do I assign to my class variable?

```
classes = [];

constructor(private navController:NavController, private httpService: HttpService) {

    this.httpService.getCalendarConfig()
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.classes = data;
            console.log("inside" + this.classes);
        });

    console.log("outside" + this.classes);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @basarat's answer:

Http is asynchronous, it doesn't return a result immediately. I would expect the code you provided in your question to produce the console log "outside" before the "inside".

The code is sending off the call to the server (`this.httpService.getCalendar...`), and then continuing on, hitting the "outside" console.log.

x time later, the server is responding with your data. It is at this point that the subscribe section is hit asynchronously, and your classes is being filled (`this.classes = data`), and your "inside" console.log is finally shown.

Comment: Thanks @Krenom, that makes sense. So how would I use that call to update my local calendar? I basically want to update the calendar when it is opened. Should I be using a different pattern from subscribe?

Comment: @JohnSmith Check out my answer from the other day for this. Essentially you have a (shared) service that pushes the values out for the components to consume: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897670/how-can-i-create-a-variable-in-a-service-that-gets-its-data-from-a-promise-yet-i/39898499#39898499

Answer (score 1):

> How do I assign to my class variable

Inside the subscribe. The moment when the *outside* code executes the value hasn't come from the server. You cannot use a value **from the future**. So you must wait for it to come back and then use it.

Comment: Thanks @basarat, so is 'subscribe' the wrong pattern for my use case? When the class is initialised I want to update the calendar. Is that just a simple call to the server rather than subscribe? How would I achieve that?

Comment: subscribe is the correct pattern. However you need to show a spinner (or some other indicator) till the results come back from the server.